# Dagger2.10+: Inject ViewModel in Fragment/Activity which has run-time dependencies

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, assisted-inject

For `ViewModels` which has only **compile-time** dependencies, I use the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` from Architecture components like following:

```
class ViewModelFactory<T : ViewModel> @Inject constructor(private val viewModel: Lazy<T>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModel.get() as T
}
```

And in my `Activity` or `Fragment` I get the `ViewModel` in following way:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory<ProductsViewModel>
```

This is working fine until my `ViewModel` needs a dependency which is only available at **run-time**.

Scenario is, I have a list of `Product` which I am displaying in `RecyclerView`. For each `Product`, I have `ProductViewModel`.

Now, the `ProductViewModel` needs variety of dependencies like `ResourceProvider`, `AlertManager`etc which are available compile-time and I can either `Inject` them using `constructor` or I can `Provide` them using `Module`. But, along with above dependencies, it needs `Product` object as well which is only available at run-time as I fetch the list of products via API call.

I don't know how to inject a dependency which is only available at run-time. So I am doing following at the moment:

`ProductsFragment.kt`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        productsAdapter = ProductsAdapter(context!!, products, R.layout.list_item_products, BR.productVm)
        rvProducts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvProducts.addItemDecoration(RecyclerViewMargin(context, 10, 20))
        rvProducts.adapter = productsAdapter
        getProducts()
    }

private fun getProducts() {
    productsViewModel.getProducts()
            .observe(this, Observer { productResponse: GetProductResponse ->
                products.clear()
                productsAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                val productsViewModels = productResponse.data.map { product ->
                   // Here product is fetched run-time and alertManager etc are
                   // injected into Fragment as they are available compile-time. I
                   // don't think this is correct approach and I want to get the
                   // ProductViewModel using Dagger only.
                    ProductViewModel(product, resourceProvider,
                            appUtils, alertManager)
                }
                products.addAll(productsViewModels)
                productsAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            })
}
```

`ProductsAdapter` binds the `ProductViewModel` with the `list_item_products` layout.

As I mentioned in comments in the code, I don't want to create `ProductViewModel` my self and instead I want it from dagger only. I also believe the correct approach would be to **Inject** the `ProductsAdapter` directly into the `Fragment`, but then also, I need to tell dagger from where it can get `Product` object for `ProductViewModel` which is available at run time and it ends up on same question for me.

Any guide or directions to achieve this would be really great.

Comment: Have you tried [AssistedInject](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject) ? I think this is what you are looking for. I also have [this article](https://coroutinedispatcher.blogspot.com/2019/08/how-to-produce-savedstatehandle-in-your.html) in case you want to know how to use it.

Comment: duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799407/looking-for-an-example-for-dagger-assisted-injection) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175014/can-i-use-some-kind-of-assisted-inject-with-dagger)

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Thanks for the link, I'll check it quickly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right direction in wanting to inject dependencies instead of creating them like you are doing with `ProductViewModel`. But, yes, you can't inject ProductViewModel as it needs a Product which is only available a runtime.

The solution to this problem is to create a Factory of ProductViewModel:

```
class ProductViewModel(
    val product: Product, 
    val resourceProvider: ResourceProvider,
    val appUtils: AppUtils, 
    val alertManager: AlertManager
) {
// ...
}

class ProductViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    val resourceProvider: ResourceProvider,
    val appUtils: AppUtils, 
    val alertManager: AlertManager
) {
    fun create(product: Product): ProductViewModel {
        return ProductViewModel(product, resourceProvider, appUtils, alertManager)
    }  
}
```

Then inject `ProductViewModelFactory` in your `ProductsFragment` class, and call `productViewModelFactory.create(product)` when the Product is available.

---

As your project start getting bigger and you see this pattern repeating, consider using [AssistedInject](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject) to reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: Looks like a way to go. Thanks, I'll check this by implementing shortly :)